# Eclipse plugin view does not show up after install

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I created a sample plugin which includes a simple view in eclipse and ran the plugin from inside the workbench, my plugin is installed and I get my view showing up in Window/Show View/Other... . I packaged the plugin as a jar file and installed it under the plugins directory of eclipse and restarted my eclipse workbench. I am not able to find my plugin view. I dont know whats is wrong

I am using eclipse RCP SR2 (3.6) for developing plugins and my packaged jar file includes the code, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml files.

I created the plugin from the book 'Eclipse Plug-ins, 3rd Edition'. I followed the steps outright and am not able to set up the plugin as a jar file.

---

I got it to work somehow? The plug-in project was created using Execution Environment JavaSE-1.6. 'It was given in the book I referred'. Now the manifest editor had the entry 'Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6'. Now I ran the application with-in eclipse, it was working. But when I bundled the plugin as jar and copied the plug-in jar under plugins folder and restarted eclipse the plugin was not working, I dont know why, I thought my eclipse is not running under JRE1.6, but I checked my Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs-> I have only jdk1.6.0_27 checked (So I assume that the eclipse is running under JavaSE1.6). This is bit confusing for me! I removed the Execution Environment entry in the Manifest editor Overview tab. Now there is no 'Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment' entry in my Manifest, I created the bundle jar again and installed in eclipse plugins folder and restarted eclipse using -clean option. It started working in my eclipse. I got it to work somehow but with no understanding! I am still looking for answers from some one who can help me figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Open an OSGI console and type 'ss'. It should list all of the plugins. Can you see it? What is the state of it.

You can use Preferences/plug-in development/target platform edit running 'running platform' content tab to list and check/uncheck plugins. I hope it helps.

You could try copying your jar file to the eclipse/dropins folder.

Comment: I am able to run my plug-in within eclipse as Run As -> Eclipse Application. I created a plug-in jar file and copied the jar file under plug-ins directory my eclipse and started my eclipse, but my views are not showing up in this eclipse where I installed the plug-in."You could try copying your jar file to the eclipse/dropins folder." ->> This is not working either.

Comment: "You could try copying your jar file to the eclipse/dropins folder." ->> This is not working either.

Comment: "Open an OSGI console and type 'ss'. It should list all of the plugins. Can you see it? What is the state of it."->> I opened the console from Run As ->> OSGi Framework ->> New Configurations, in my Bundles tab I had 'Workspace' and 'Target Platform'. I unchecked my plugin in Workspace and checked it under 'Target Platform'. I ran the code, and I got 'INSTALLED   com.qualityeclipse.favorites_1.0.0' under OSGi console after typing 'ss', but my view is not showed under 'Window/Show View/Other...'

Comment: How did you create that jar file? You can export plugins and/or features by file/export/Plug-in development/deployable plugins and fragments. This might help if you haven't tried it.